# how to write centered plus minus 1 in inline math mode in latex

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, inline

I want to write y belongs to plus minus 1 but i do not know how to write it. My code is as below:

```
\begin{document}  
 $y\in$ +- 1
\end{document
```

but it is not giving centered plus minus 1.

Comment: use `$y\in \pm 1$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using math mode (best solution):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}  
 $y \pm 1$
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use math mode (worst solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}  
 $y$ \textpm 1
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be math-mode, the other solution canot be a good deal.

Comment: @Johannes_B I prefer math-mode too but the code provide by the OP is not in math-mode for the second part, so I put it too

Comment: The simple reason for that might be: The OP doesn't know that the whole thing is one entity that should typeset in math mode.

Comment: I prefer the first answer, as it is what i need, second alternative (If you don't want to use math mode (as your MWE) is not what i mean to do. Any ways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake as @Johannes_B told, i forgot to end $ after 1 but i meant to do that only.